# Make inner join between tables that are in two different Databases

Tags: sql-server

Is it OK to query between to different databases that are on different IP addresses?

For example is it OK to `inner join` them?

No code cause I don't know how to provide.

If you use

```
sp_addlinkedserver
```

from another IP address does it mean SQL Server creates an instance of that database every time SP is called?

If I create a dummy database on first database of second database then does SQL Server consider the second database as local resource or not (when calling `sp_addlinkedserver`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a linked server using `sp_addlinkedserver`, which you typically only do once. This will create a connection to the other SQL Server which can referenced from the server on which you create it. You can then query the other server. Though, it's usually not considered best practice to join tables over a linked server, because this can result in the referenced table being transfered in its entirety to the local servers `TempDB` which might be non-performant (compared to doing the same operation on the potential limited, needed set of data) and cause heavy operations.

Creating the linked server will not move any data to the server on which it is created.

Comment: By your advice I did use factory pattern for db context of my code that used differenct connection string for every data base